# Unwanted iteration in tkinter result

Tags: python, tkinter

Iam trying to obtain method of payment from user through tkinter radiobuttons as follows:

```
payment_method_label=Label(root,text="Select Payment Method:")
payment_method=StringVar()
payment_method.set("card")
cards=Radiobutton(root,text="Debit/Credit Card",variable=payment_method,value="card",anchor='w')
wallet=Radiobutton(root,text="Payment Wallet",variable=payment_method,value="wallet",anchor='w')
netbanking=Radiobutton(root,text="Net Banking",variable=payment_method,value="net banking",anchor='w')
```

Here's the result:
[image: Payment methods]

You can clearly see that there is unforeseen iteration (the radiobuttons are going in a slanting order)

As you can see from the code, I tried using the `anchor="w"`, but that doesn't make any difference.

Can anyone please pinpoint whats going wrong here?

All help is appreciated
Thanks!

Comment: Using `anchor` option on the radiobutton will just align the text to west and not the widget on whole wont be placed to west. So you have to use `pack(anchor='w')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = Tk()

payment_method_label=Label(root,text="Select Payment Method:")
payment_method=StringVar()
payment_method.set("card")
cards=Radiobutton(root,text="Debit/Credit Card",variable=payment_method,value="card").pack(anchor=tk.W)
wallet=Radiobutton(root,text="Payment Wallet",variable=payment_method,value="wallet").pack(anchor=tk.W)
netbanking=Radiobutton(root,text="Net Banking",variable=payment_method,value="net banking").pack(anchor=tk.W)

root.mainloop()
```

Use `.pack(anchor=tk.W)` at the end of each radiobutton. You don't this `anchor='w'` parameter for the radiobutton.

[image]

I guess this was the output you expected.

## Grid Method

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = Tk()

payment_method_label=Label(root,text="Select Payment Method:")
payment_method=StringVar()
payment_method.set("card")
cards=Radiobutton(root,text="Debit/Credit Card",variable=payment_method,value="card").grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="w")
wallet=Radiobutton(root,text="Payment Wallet",variable=payment_method,value="wallet").grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="w")
netbanking=Radiobutton(root,text="Net Banking",variable=payment_method,value="net banking").grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="w")

root.mainloop()
```

Use `sticky="W"`

Comment: You can replace `.pack(anchor=tk.W)` with `.pack(anchor='w')` its all the same, is what i believe and multiple imports of `tkinter` is not really necessary, though you can use it to show that `W` is a tkinter variable. Also all your radiobuttons are `None` here and hence cannot be reused

Comment: @Pro Chess I want it with grid as shown in code. This is not working with grid

Comment: @SumathiIyengar You did not mention about  `grid()` or `pack()` in the your sample code, anyway with grid use `grid(...,sticky='w')`

Comment: @SumathiIyengar Sorry about that. I have edited my post on how to use it with grid method

Comment: @Cool Cloud My fault. Sorry about that. Thanks anyways. Works wonderfully now

Answer (score 2):

When you use `anchor` parameter while creating the radiobutton, the anchor parameter determines where the radiobutton will be, if it occupies a space larger than it needs. For instance:

```
tk.Radiobutton(root,text="foo",width=100,anchor="e")
```

will create a radiobutton which is 100 characters large and the text will be attached to east.

In your case it is not what you want. You want your radiobutton to be attached to the west side of the column. Thus, you need to use the `sticky` parameter with `.grid()`.

So, let's get back to your example, what you need to do is:

```
cards=Radiobutton(root,text="Debit/Credit Card",variable=payment_method,value="card")
wallet=Radiobutton(root,text="Payment Wallet",variable=payment_method,value="wallet")
netbanking=Radiobutton(root,text="Net Banking",variable=payment_method,value="net banking")

cards.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="w")
wallet.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="w")
netbanking.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky="w")
```